# Background is cut off after starting to scroll?

Tags: html, css

You can view the page I'm having a problem with here:  http://www.easythemepro.com/themes.php

The background is cut off about half way down for some reason.  I have it set to 100% height but that doesn't appear to be working...

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #D5D5D5;
    height: 100%
    box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here... It looks like it should be working properly to me.

Comment: Use some javascript to make it reference it to the document height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are creating the bg with css, If you are not going to use javascript probably you need to use a image instead and use `background-attachment:fixed;`

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have inner shadow to your html, also you don't need to have so many styles for your body background. I see that you are using a `1x1` images for your background you can use `#D5D5D5` instead that image. and this is no need for `backgrond-position` or `background-repeat` use this CSS:

```
html{
    box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    /* other styles if you have */
}

body{
    background:#d5d5d5;
    /* and remove other background styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`body,html {`
    `font-family: sans-serif;`
    `font-size: 12px;`
    `line-height: 1.4em;`
    `width: 100%;`
    `background: #D5D5D5;`
    `height: 100%`
    `box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;`
    `overflow: auto;`
`}`